# Mutations in a Petri dish overnight

Tags: bacteriology, mutations, ecoli

How long does it take for a bacterial culture in a Petri dish to experience all possible single base pair mutations? Can 12 hours be enough?

I want to get an intuition for whether a given mutation is a rare event we can only hope for or something that is all but guaranteed to happen.

Comment: Remember that not every mutation is beneficial or conveys some sort of survival advantage, especially in a rich environment like a Petri dish where you are theoretically growing the bacteria on some sort of nutrient agar or in a nutrient-containing solution. Also remember that *populations* evolve, not individuals.

Comment: Sure! Maybe I should delete the last paragraph. The surprising part for me just that mutation is not a matter of "if" but "when". Like in https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6242871/ I can see antibiotics resistance evolve in a matter of days. Super cool.

Comment: A number that gets passed on will be in the non-coding set, I wonder where they get the value for P - presumably from viable specimens, or is it total likely mutations... Question followed.

Comment: I don't understand your question, as you give no value for P. Are you saying that the twit quoted some value and you wish to know what it is? In which case your question would appear to be "What is the frequency of mutations per base-pair of E.coli during cell division?" and by extension "How many mutations occur in a petri dish in a period of (say) 24h, and how does this compare with the number of base pairs of DNA in the E.coli genome?". If this is the case please say so explicitly.

Comment: @David: Thanks! Yes, that's exactly the case. I've updated the question to be clearer. I'll also try to add an answer based on what I can Google.

Comment: It occurs to me that you might be interested also in our sister site, [skeptics.se]. They specialise in challenging notable unreferenced claims in the various media.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Good point! But I can't even find the claim. I decided to cut down the question radically and just ask about how long it takes to get all point mutations. I also cobbled together an answer.

Comment: Note that your question, while it takes the usual framing of single base pair mutations, ignores a very large number of possible mutations in the form of structural rearrangements, transpositions, etc., which do most of the real work of changing genomes. Contrary to single-base mutations, there is no way to saturate the space of all such mutations in culture.

Answer (score 3):

We can calculate the number of base pair copy errors in a Petri dish per hour by multiplying the number of base pairs (B), the copy error rate (P), the number of divisions in an hour (D), and the number of cells in a Petri dish (N). (We assume a stable population in a saturated medium.)

$$
B \times P \times D \times N
$$

I've looked up some articles and tried to pull out numbers from them:

- **B:** E. coli has 4.6 million base pairs. [1]
- **P:** Mutation rate per base pair per generation is around $10^{-10}$. [1][2]
- **D:** The doubling time can be as little as 20 minutes. So 3 divisions per hour. [3]
- **N:** Around a billion E. coli per ml. [4] A few billion in a "colony". [5] Let's call it 3 billion for the Petri dish.

$$
B \times P \times D \times N
= 4.6 \times 10^6 \times10^{-10} \times 3 \times 3 \times 10^{9}
$$

This comes out to 0.9 mutations on average per base pair per hour.
Each base pair can change into 3 different base pairs. After 3 hours we will have had almost as many mutations as possible! We can get the same mutation multiple times. But even accounting for that, it's almost certain that a given mutation will happen within a day:

[image: probability of a given mutation over time]

(Click the chart for an interactive view where you can try different numbers.)

Indeed we can see research [6] where selection can give rise to new mutant strains every day:

[image: Doxycycline resistance evolving on SAGE plates over 6 days]

In general if the inverse of the base pair copy error rate is close to the population size, we will see a large subset of all possible single base pair mutations in each generation.

How likely it is that truly 100% of mutations have happened is known as the ["coupon collector's problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). Its solution tells us that the expected number of mutations needed to cover all 3 × 4.6 million point mutations is $3 B \times log(3 B)$. With our numbers above we are doing around 4.1 million mutations per hour, so we would on average need around 55 hours.

1. [Spontaneous mutation rates come into focus in Escherichia coli](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.dnarep.2014.09.009), 2014 by A B Williams
2. [DNA replication fidelity in Escherichia coli: a multi-DNA polymerase affair](https://dx.doi.org/10.1111%2Fj.1574-6976.2012.00338.x), 2012 by I J Fijalkowska, R M Schaaper, and P Jonczyk
3. [Organization of sister origins and replisomes during multifork DNA replication in Escherichia coli](https://dx.doi.org/10.1038%2Fsj.emboj.7601871), 2007 by S Fossum, E Crooke, and K Skarstad
4. [General calibration of microbial growth in microplate readers](https://doi.org/10.1038/srep38828), 2016 by K Stevenson, A F McVey, I B N Clark, P S Swain, and T Pilizota
5. [Role of the RuvAB protein in avoiding spontaneous formation
   of deletion mutations in the Escherichia coli K-12 endogenous tonB gene](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.bbrc.2004.08.078), 2004 by K Mashimo, Y Nagata, M Kawata, H Iwasaki, and K Yamamoto
6. [Access to high-impact mutations constrains the evolution of antibiotic resistance in soft agar](https://dx.doi.org/10.1038%2Fs41598-018-34911-9), 2018 by N Ghaddar, M Hashemidahaj, and B L Findlay

Comment: The tweet was from an expert and I don't know the first thing about any of this. So I'm pretty sure this answer is wrong. But which part?

Comment: I got the whole formula wrong! That's error rate PER BASE PAIR. Then the claim is 100% good. I'll fix this!

Comment: All fixed. I'm quite unsure about the number of cells. But https://doi.org/10.1016/j.bbrc.2004.08.078 also gives cell counts in the billions so I hope it's roughly correct.

Comment: One needs to compare the total number of mutations, $P\times D\times N \times T$ with the total number of base pairs $B$. If $P\times D\times N \times T > B$, i.e., $P\times D\times N \times T/B >1$, then the mutations explore all of the genome. In fact the condition is even more stringent, if we take into account that it is a stochastic process, i.e., some bases will mutate multiple number of times.

Comment: 10 mL is a very large volume of cells to be growing on a plate (solid media). Cells do not grow in the medium but on top of it. I would suggest instead using a number of cells in a colony 3.3e9 (https://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/bionumber.aspx?s=n&v=6&id=104458). Alternatively, one could instead assume that the culture is in liquid medium of 10 mL, in which case your 1 billion cell number is close (though other estimates are higher, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3146540/).

Comment: Additionally, on the right side of your equation you still have $T$, but you also have a "3" (?). I think that you meant to remove the last $\times T$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! @RogerVadim: But P is the error rate _per base pair_. So you will have $B\times P$ mutations for each division.

Comment: @MaximillianPress: Thanks, I'll use the colony size. It's the same ballpark. The 3 is there because we have 3 divisions per hour. $T$ is the number of hours.

Comment: I'll just drop $T$ and talk about mutations per hour! There are so many variables already anyway!

Comment: @RogerVadim: "In fact the condition is even more stringent, if we take into account that it is a stochastic process, i.e., some bases will mutate multiple number of times." I've added a paragraph to address this too. Looks like this pushes out the timeline a bit! Thanks!

Comment: @DanielDarabos Another thing that is missing is that the number of cells is treated as a constant, although they divide, i.e., it grows geometriclally (unless we also allow them to die).

Comment: Oh man. I was hoping the population stabilizes at some point. ($N$) But maybe they just stop dividing when they go hungry?!

Comment: @DanielDarabos it stabilizes, because many mutations are deleterious and/or because there are limited food supplies... in which case they either do not divide or there is strong selection. I think you need to ask a more pointed question: do you want to know how many mutations are there *or* whether all the mutations have been explored? Under what conditions they grow (in terms of food, selection, growth rate, etc.) - if they do not replicate, why use doubling time?

Comment: Yeah. Whether we want to go into that I think depends on why we are asking the question. I edited it now to say that my goal was just to get an intuition for how likely it is to get a specific mutation in a day. On that I'm satisfied even if the answer is lax on population size. I'll also add to the answer a practical example where selection is used to force mutations in a matter of days.

Comment: Be careful about what you call a *specific mutation*. You proved that each site might have experienced a mutation over the night, but it doesn't mean that all the possible genomes were explored: for $B$ base pairs one may have $4^B$ different genomes - it would take much longer to explore all of them.

Comment: @RogerVadim: You're right! I forgot this is not binary! I think I've fixed it now. I've also added an interactive thing where you can change the parameters and see how the probability over time changes. Even if we consider 3 mutations per bp, the probability goes up very high in 16 hours or so. Thanks for all the help!